# Start/Stop services in specific order only if previously running

Tags: vbscript

```
sComputer = "."
Set Runninglist = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
aTargetSvcs= Array ("pageserver","CacheServer","CrystalAPS","CrystalInputFileServer","CrystalOutputFileServer","CrystalReportApplicationServer", "JobServer_Report" )
Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationlevel=impersonate}!\\" _
& sComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set cServices = oWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service")
For Each oService In cServices
For Each sTargetSvc In aTargetSvcs
If LCase(oService.Name) = LCase(sTargetSvc) Then

If oService.State <> "Started" Then
Runninglist.Add oService.Name
  oService.StopService()    
 End If
End if
Next
Next

WScript.Sleep 3000

For Each oService In cServices
For Each sTargetSvc In Runninglist
If LCase(oService.Name) = LCase(sTargetSvc) Then
oService.StartService()
End If
Next
Next
```

GOAL: I want to Start the service from Runninglist in this order only if they were previously stopped: 
CrystalAPS 
Crystal Input File Repository Server 
 
Crystal Output File Repository Server 
Crystal Report Application Server 
Crystal Report Job Server 
Crystal Cache Server 
Crystal Page Server

Comment: Why don't you simply define dependencies between those services?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to exploit two facts:

1. A VBScript dictionary keeps a stable order of entry
2. WMI loop objects can be stored for later use

In code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim dicSrvOrd : Set dicSrvOrd = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dicSrvOrd.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
Set dicSrvOrd("SQLWriter") = Nothing
Set dicSrvOrd("Browser")   = Nothing
Set dicSrvOrd("Alerter")   = Nothing

Dim oService
For Each oService In GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationlevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service")
    If dicSrvOrd.Exists(oService.Name) Then
       If "Running" = oService.State Then
          WScript.Echo "stopping", oService.Name, "(was", oService.State & ")"
          Set dicSrvOrd(oService.Name) = oService
       Else
          WScript.Echo oService.Name, oService.State
       End If
    Else
       ' WScript.Echo "don't care for", oService.Name
    End If
Next
WScript.Echo "--------------"
Dim sSrv
For Each sSrv In dicSrvOrd.Keys()
    If Not dicSrvOrd(sSrv) Is Nothing Then
       WScript.Echo "starting", dicSrvOrd(sSrv).Name
    End If
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 22131182.vbs
Alerter Stopped
stopping Browser (was Running)
stopping SQLWriter (was Running)
--------------
starting SQLWriter
starting Browser
```